# Mysql : how to escape double quote?

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to escape double quote (") with :

```
    UPDATE articles
    SET body = REPLACE(body, '"', '\"')
    WHERE body LIKE '%"%'
```

Nothing is replaced.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to escape the double quote. You need to escape the '\' so it should be `'\\"'` because it is an escape character for mysql

Comment: It seems undesirable to me to introduce random escapes into your article body.  Backslashes preceding double spaces is only a very small part of escaping text in only the backslash escape syntax of may escape syntaxes.  I highly recommend you make `body` an exact representation of the article body.  If you're motivated to escape double quotes it probably means you're probably interpolating the article body into qouted variable values - if so, I encourage you to find a different way.

Comment: @JorgeCampos You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do so, because I couldn't produce a valid csv because of the double quotes (").

Comment: @Barmar done. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape the double quote. You need to escape the `\` so it should be '\"' because it is an escape character for MySQL. so your command should be:

```
UPDATE articles
   SET body = REPLACE(body, '"', '\\"')
 WHERE body LIKE '%"%'
```

Take look at the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) so you can have more information on it.